# Laravel: Storage работа с изображениями

Tags: php, laravel, storage

Нужна помощь, столкнулся с такой ситацией, нужно взять файл изменить его размер(обрезать) и записать в директорию используя Storage. Я обращаюсь к файлу и записываю, а вот как изменить его размер(обрезать) незнаю, использовал **imagecopyresampled**, **imagecreatefromjpeg**, **imagejpeg**, но с Storage не получается их использовать.

```
$filename = \Auth::id().'.jpg';
$content = Storage::disk('photos')->get('8.1438179120.jpg');
\Storage::disk('photos')->put($filename, $content);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать готовую библиотеку для работы с изображениями. 
К примеру: https://github.com/Intervention/image

А вот собственно для обрезки метод из документации этой библиотеки:
http://image.intervention.io/api/crop

Пример:

```
$img = Image::make($source);
$img->crop($width, $height, $x, $y);
Storage::disk('images')->put($filename, $img->stream()->__toString());
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо:)